# Desktop freezes minutes after reboot following upgrade

Tags: upgrade, freeze, 23.04

I've been using Ubuntu and Linux for only six months. Yesterday, I upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04. Now, when the desktop appears after boot, two things are different in 23.04 than 22.10. First, there is no wallpaper (which is no big deal). Second and most importantly, I can use the mouse for a few minutes until the mouse freezes. Sometimes I can open an application, sometimes after clicking applications won't open. Sometimes I can open terminal or a browser for example. Eventually the mouse freezes permanently. I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting or what else to report. OS installed on Apple MacBook Pro "Core 2 Duo" 2.8 17" Mid-2009. During the boot process there is some new messages that include this text "clearing orphaned inode"Thanks. I'm trying the app boot repair from the live USB. I get this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CZvrkTNc43/

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

### The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda5,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Is there anyway to re-do the upgrade without doing a clean install? The fixes from boot repair did not do anything.

The history.log file says:

Start-Date: 2023-05-13  22:09:28
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.118'
Upgrade: tzdata:amd64 (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.10.0, 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), libldap-common:amd64 (2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.10.2), libgdm1:amd64 (43.0-1ubuntu1, 43.0-1ubuntu1.22.10.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-0:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), libfreetype6:amd64 (2.12.1+dfsg-3, 2.12.1+dfsg-3ubuntu0.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.1:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-5.0-0:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.1:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), libllvm15:amd64 (1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.10.2, 1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), libldap-2.5-0:amd64 (2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.5.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.10.2), gdm3:amd64 (43.0-1ubuntu1, 43.0-1ubuntu1.22.10.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.54ubuntu0.2, 0.54ubuntu0.3), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (43.0-1ubuntu1, 43.0-1ubuntu1.22.10.1), libwebkit2gtk-5.0-0:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.38.5-0ubuntu0.22.10.1, 2.38.6-0ubuntu0.22.10.1), thermald:amd64 (2.5.1-1, 2.5.1-1ubuntu1), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.13.6~22.10.1, 27.14.4~22.10)
End-Date: 2023-05-13  22:11:10

Comment: "No wallpaper" suggests that your upgrade was broken or incomplete. Review your /var/log/apt/history.log.

Comment: How do I repair a broken upgrade?

Comment: First you review your log to determine that's the actual problem. Trying random solutions without understanding the problem will surely make things worse.

Comment: thanks. I can't get to that file from the broken install because it crashes. Can I access this file from the live USB?

Comment: Most folks can.

Comment: I posted the content of history.log in the original post. Unfortunately, I am unable to understand what it says or what I should do based on what it says. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, let's think about it: A release-upgrade from 22.10 to 23.04 involves upgrading thousands of packages. Since thousands of packages are not listed, it seems unlikely that you did a successful release-upgrade. Since nearly all those packages are tagged "22.10," I'm not seeing the release-upgrade at all. Browse through your other logfiles in /var/log, and see if you can find evidence of a successful or unsuccessful release-upgrade. Learning how to read your logs is an important part of learning to use Ubuntu effectively.

Comment: Yes I see that upgrade was unsuccessful and I see what my prior upgrades looked like and that they are much longer. Thank you for showing me that. What do you recommend now to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Depends upon *why* your upgrade was unsuccessful, Looking for that reason is why you review the logs. Look for the specific error(s) logged, and add those to your question.

Comment: My internet was not working well last night when I did this. I should have reset before I installed. I reset it today.  I've had several successful upgrades before this. I suspect the slow and choppy internet is what caused the problem. What files would show the specific errors? What would they say?